# CSS Does Not Load With 500 Error When Using Non-English Language in WebSphere 7 Using IIS WebSphere Plugin

Tags: css, iis, websphere, jasperserver, websphere-7

I am having an issue with an application (Jasper Reports Server) hosted on WebSphere behind an IIS web server.

When loading a web page, it attempts to load the CSS which generates a 500 error and is unable to load the CSS. This only occurs when the clients language is something other than English. E.g. If I use IE and change the language to only include Japanese I can reproduce the error.

In the WebSphere IIS plugin logs, the following gets generated:

```
[Tue Nov 24 09:44:37 2015] 000014e0 00000dcc - ERROR: ESI: esiResponseCreate: invalid Last-Modified header value: 0xffffffff
```

When I look up the error, it doesn't provide any help other than contact IBM support or workaround being to add the English language in.

I have also set the logs to TRACE but don't see anything helpful so far.

I can also run another Fiddler (HTTP network trace) to provide more information but will need a suggestion on what to look for.

This seems like a configuration issue because another application (Proprietary) we are running on the same configuration loads the CSS fine with the other language.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your java application likely sets its own Last-Modified header on the HTTP response but (incorrectly) translates the value into some local language. The spec does not permit a localized date string.

You can verify by enabling TRACE or DETAIL level logging in plugin-cfg.xml, or just hit the app directly in the JVM and look at the Last-Modified returned.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to get this to work through the web server by disabling ESI in the plugin-cfg.xml / Integrated Solutions Console. That however seems like a workaround and I don't know the impact of disabling ESI. Regarding the Last-Modified header, it returned "Last-Modified: , 30 8 2014 06:20:52 UTC". I got this by accessing the JVM directly but please note that when I access it directly, it loads the CSS properly.

Comment: That is definitely an invalid string for a date header

Comment: ESI processing is something I generally tell people to turn off  at step1.  For one, it causes responses to be buffered.  You're not losing much.